# While moving files, how to continue without halting if an error happens?

Tags: files, file-transfer, file-manager, mc

Imagine you have 1000 files. You move/copy to a different folder.
You start the process, all going well, **you leave the computer**.
At file number 10 an error dialog states if you want to overwrite, rename, cancel, etc.

You come back hours later thinking it should be done by now, to find that it halted waiting for your confirmation. And you still need to move/copy the 990 files.

Is there a way to move/copy, skipping problematic transactions until the end? (for you to review them then)

(not just "overwrite all" or "skip all", but to allow me to decide at the end, and keep copying until then)

I'm currently using MC or just any file manager, and I've never seen this option. Can this be done?

Thanks!

Comment: There is `rsync`. Will that do?

Comment: A shell script using the `--no-clobber` option for `cp` or `mv` together with the `--verbose` option would prevent *problematic transactions* while logging them.

Comment: Anything more user friendly than rsync? (not rsync gui)